# How to configure concurrent rabbitmq listener in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

I've setup a minimal Spring Boot project with RabbitMQ support, and my consumer looks like this:

```
package app.mq.consumers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListener;
import java.util.Date;

@Component
public final class StdoutConsumer {

  @RabbitListener(
    queues = {"stdout-q"},
    concurrency = "5",
    autoStartup = "true",
    exclusive = false
  )
  public void receiveMessage(Object message) throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println(new Date());
  }
}
```

It just sleeps 1 second and print a timestamp to the stdout.

And here is the `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    host: localhost
    port: 5672
    username: guest
    password: guest
```

That's all. Everything else is absolutely untouched.

I pushed 30 messages into the RabbitMQ then started the Spring Boot app, and I expected to see 5 timestamps printed at roughly the same time (because I set the `concurrency` to `"5"`), and after 1 second, next 5 timestamps, so on and so forth. However, what I saw is that the timestamps are printed one by one, with the interval between any 2 timestamps is roughly 1 second. If I change the code to sleep 5 seconds, then the interval between each 2 timestamps becomes 5 seconds.

[image: Pre-populated RabbitMQ queue]

[image: Timestamps printed]

However, when I first start up the Spring Boot app then quickly push messages into the MQ, the 5 consumers do work concurrently.

[image: Populate the queue on the fly]

[image: Consumers work concurrently]

I guess the issue comes from the initialization phase of the consumers, but why the Spring framework initialize the consumers all at once? How can I make them start at once instead of one by one?

Comment: When checking the documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#listener-concurrency), my understanding is that the container waits a while before adding consumers. Can you try with more messages (maybe 20) and check if you eventually have more consumers.

Comment: @SherifBehna I actually have tried that, with 30 messages in the MQ, and it took 30 seconds to print them all. Funny thing is, if I start the spring boot app first, then quickly push loads of messages into the MQ, the consumers do work concurrently.